# Cannot start KVM machine on arch after update

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, kvm, qemu, spice

I'm having trouble with a VM I was using yesterday. After using, I closed the guest and updated my host machine (arch linux). Today I turned on the host and tried to turn on my guest and this message appeared:

> Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc'
> not supported without spice graphics
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in
> cb_wrapper
> callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
> callback(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line
> 57, in newfn
> ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in
> startup
> self._backend.create()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1352, in create
> raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed') libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc'
> not supported without spice graphics

I'm using a dedicated nvidia card on a manjaro guest OS.

**I'm not a linux expert.**

Any idea what might be happening and how to fix this?

Any other info you need let me know.

**UPDATE #1:**

I removed the usb spice redirectors from my VM:

```
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
</redirdev>
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
</redirdev>
```

And now it works fine... I just can't have usb redirectors on the guest OS now... Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: You should probably edit your question (and its title) to better reflect what you're now asking for help on.

Comment: Do the instructions at https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE (skip to "Enabling SPICE using virt-manager") help at all? I'm wondering if you've missed one of the settings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating my Arch host.  In virt-manager I went to `Display Spice` and switched Type: `VNC Server` to `Spice server` and restarted the machine.

Everything worked fine after that.

The only issue is now I have to insert my ssh-key passphrase a thousand times before getting to the console viewer.  I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also after I updated my arch linux, I then added the spice server because without the spice server I was unable to remove the two usb redirectors, I did that because I don't need them in my setup since I have a gpu passthrough vm and I use my secondary gpu for video output and I don't want to automatically redirect usb devices, read more here [https://people.freedesktop.org/~teuf/spice-doc/html/ch02s06.html](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Eteuf/spice-doc/html/ch02s06.html)